# How to POST this -d in the body of HTTP request

Tags: javascript, rest, http, google-apps-script

This is probably an easy question, but I haven't found a super clear answer.

I basically want to convert this curl POST request:

```
curl https://api.leaddyno.com/v1/affiliates \
         -d key=[YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY] \
         -d email=example@example.com
```

to an API call in Apps Scripts (I think this question goes across all languages though).

I found I could just add the -d parameters as query parameters to the end of the request, but I can't seem to pass them in the body. When passing JSON I just use JSON.stringify on a javascript object and it works great. So I guess my question is how do I format this so it has the same effect as when I make the data a query string?

This works great: `https://api.leaddyno.com/v1/affiliates?key=xxxxx&email=aaa@example.com`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `-d` options correspond to the data sent in `xmlHttpRequest.send()`.

Comment: `xhr.send("key=xxxxx&email=aaa@example.com")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data to be sent in the post body is added to the payload property of the options object you pass to UrlfetchApp.

```
var payload = {key:1233456,email:"bob@abc.edu"};
var options = {method:"POST", contentType:"application/json", payload:JSON.stringify(payload)};
var URL =" https://api.leaddyno.com/v1/affiliates";
var results = UrlfetchApp.fetch(URL,options);
```